# What is the difference between a long (luongo) and a short (ristretto) shot of espresso?

Tags: espresso

What is the difference between a long (luongo) and a short (ristretto) shot of espresso?

Is there a difference in grind, extraction time, amount of coffee used, temperature, volume of water?

If so, what are the differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A long (luongo) and a short (ristretto) shot have two key differences.

The amount of coffee used virtually stays the same although it can increase slightly with a ristretto shot, as the grind is finer.

The key similarity between these two shots and a normal shot is that the **extraction time stays the same**. *The grind is altered* to achieve this - coarser for a long shot and finer for a ristretto shot.  This, ideally, alters the volume of water which can pass through the coffee.

For a long shot, the volume should be **twice** that of a standard espresso shot and for a ristretto shot, the volume should be **half** that of a standard espresso shot.

The temperature of the water remains the same.

Comment: Can you support this with some sources? Some will serve a regular espresso cut short (e.g. at 15 seconds) as a ristretto. Can you elaborate why that wouldn't constitute a ristretto (e.g. because of how it affects flavour and texture)?

Are these two just different trains of thought (e.g. purists vs. nonpurists) or is your answer actually the consensus?

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but only in terms of *how* they are prepared. What is the differences in the resulting drink that would make someone prefer one over the other?